# "I don't know why <did I>/<I did> write it" - which is grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, word-order

Which sentence is grammatically correct?

> 1. I don't know why did I write it
> 2. I don't know why I did write it

Comment: Neither: "I don't know why I **wrote** it." You can use **did** in a slightly different sentence: "Why did I write it?"

Comment: ...although as an answer implies, the second can be used in emphasis when replying to a question, but without that context I gave the straight-forward version.

Answer (score 1):

the first one is incorrect, but the latter is true, but WHY?
one of the usages of "do", as an auxiliary verb, is to emphasize what we are saying, for example:

> He **does** look tired. (He **looks** tired)
>   He **did** at least write to say thank to you. (He at least **wrote** to say thank to you)